# Symfony Entities in a collection

Tags: php, symfony, collections, entity

I couldn't find any similar questions so here goes:

I have a Many-To-Many relationship between my (order)Flow Entity and my Product Entity, but it doesn't select an `<option>` in the `<select>`.

All the Entities has been setup by Symfony itself so the @ORM\ManyToMany etc. should be ok.

My `controller` has the following line:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new \FDM\BestilBundle\Type\FlowsType(), $flow)->add('submit', 'submit');
```

The `$flow` is populated correctly from the db.

The `FlowsType` file has amoung many fields the following code:

```
->add('product', 'collection', [
  'type' => new ProductDropdownType(),
  'allow_add' => TRUE,
  'allow_delete' => TRUE,
  'prototype' => TRUE,
  'by_reference' => FALSE,
  ]
)
```

All fields in the `FlowsType` are filled out correctly, except the one below.

The `ProductDropdownType` has the following code:

```
$builder->add('name', 'entity', [
  'class' => 'FDMBestilBundle:Flows',
  'property' => 'name',
  'by_reference' => false
]);
```

The number of rows is correct - if I have three rows in my many-to-many sql table it shows three rows. They just aren't selected.
If I change the `ProductDropdownType` to:

```
$builder->add('name', 'text');
```

The data is showing just fine - so the db and everyting is working. Except when I want a collection of `<select>`...

The relations are the following in the Entities:

In the Flow Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="FDM\BestilBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="flow")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="productsinflows",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="flow", referencedColumnName="flowId")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product", referencedColumnName="productId")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $product;
```

In the Product Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="FDM\BestilBundle\Entity\Flows", mappedBy="product")
 */
private $flow;
```

Can someone please help me - I'm stuck!

Comment: You mean your select is populated with 3 options which values are empty? i dont get "They just aren't selected"

Comment: I mean that the select tag is correctly filled with "products" data. 

But the select tag isn't selected. None of the option tags has the "selected" attribute.

One of my flow has three product in the Many-To-Many table. The page shows correctly three `select`. All three `select` has all the products from the products table. But none of the three has the selected attribute.

Comment: Can you update your answer with relations.

Comment: looks correct to me, i am not sure about collection if it takes account of relations, i know for sure that if the entity was inside your main type without collection it should be selected but since its a collection and another formtype it may not be supported

Answer (score 2):

You can use query builder in your form, this is an exemple :
In the query builder, create the SQL query with DQL

```
->add('espece', 'entity', array(
    'class'    => 'ADMapecheBundle:Espece',
    'property' => 'nom',
    'multiple' => false,
    'query_builder' => function(EspeceRepository $er) use ($user) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                            ->where("p.user = :user")
                            ->orderBy('p.nom', 'ASC')
                            ->setParameter('user', $user);
```

I hope to help you, friendly

Comment: Hi Capt. what does your EspeceRepository file look like? And where do you get the $user object/variable from?

Comment: i believe this was just a piece of his code isn't adapted to your code, but this is not what you are looking for, you already have your data, query_builder is used if you need special query for the entities, but he want all i guess

Comment: The user object is a where close for my query and my EspeceRepository is call to set Type of the query result, it is empty.